# Allocate multiple variables at once with SOURCE=

Tags: fortran, fortran2003, fortran2008

I am now trying to update my old Fortran code that includes the lines like (*)

```
allocate( a(2), b(2) )
a(:) = 0.0
b(:) = 0.0
```

Initially, I changed them to

```
allocate( a(2), source=0.0 )
allocate( b(2), source=0.0 )
```

but this is clearly not much simple. So I tried to combine them so that

```
allocate( a(2), b(2), source=0.0 )    !! (1)
```

I didn't expect it to work, but it actually worked for gfortran >=4.8 and Sun fortran 8.7 (while not for ifort-14). So I went through the ALLOCATE section of the [F2003](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/04/04-007.pdf) and [F2008](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) documents, and it seems that the restriction has been removed in F2008 that "If SOURCE= appears, *allocation-list* shall contain only one *allocate-object*". Does this mean that the above line 1 is no problem in F2008, and that the different behavior is simply due to different degree of F2008 support?

(*) In actual codes, I was trying to allocate several array components of a derived type, `allocate( conf% crd(3,N), conf% vel(3,N), conf% frc(3,N), blah, blah,... )` while assigning zero to each of them. So I was wondering if it is possible to simplify those lines somewhat.

Comment: Very simply: yes.  Assuming both `a` and `b` are type compatible with `0.0`.

Comment: @francescalus OK thanks :) I feel this is very convenient if many compilers will support...

Comment: Be aware, though: some versions of ifort implement the syntax rules of F2008, but don't correctly do the sourcing.  [That is, the compiler will silently not give the correct result of the sourced allocation.]

Comment: Hmmmm, really... (Indeed, even in the above case, ifort14 compiled and ran silently with wrong results; with -check, it aborted with message.) Then it may be better to stick to single-variable sourced allocation (if it is necessary).

Comment: `a = [ 0.0, 0.0 ] ; b = a`

Comment: > francescalus, Thanks, I will check a bit more on the Standards documents and to see my (another question) is worth posting (it may be simply related to type matching issues). @IanH Thanks for the tips; yes, it is surely another way, but I wanted to do this for more variables (see the Edit). If I define some Fortran routines like `zeros( dims )` (by mimicking Python etc), it may be actually clear to use automatic reallocation of LHS (e.g., a = zeros( N ); b = zeros( N )).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the high level, yes, the restriction in Fortran 2003 that there is only one object in a sourced allocation is removed in Fortran 2008.

Now, on to other matters.  First, you don't show the declarations of `a` and `b`.  In a sourced allocation the objects to be allocated must be type compatible with the source.  The simple case

```
real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a, b
allocate( a(2), b(2) )
a(:) = 0.0
b(:) = 0.0
```

has the same Fortran 2008 effect as

```
real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a, b
allocate( a(2), b(2), source=0.0 )
```

But what about

```
double precision, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a, b
allocate( a(2), b(2), source=0.0 )
```

?

And the second point from before is: Fortran 2008 is a relatively new thing.  I don't trust all compilers to correctly implement the rules with multiple objects in a sourced allocation.

Comment: Yeah, my test code is exactly like "real, allocatable ::" thing, so it is compatible with 0.0 (single-precision real). But even with "double precision, allocatable :: ", doesn't it work correctly because 0.0 is exactly representable with single-precision...? Or is it actually dangerous because of bit-wise copy thing??

Comment: It's that a double precision is not type compatible with a default real. That is the second sourced allocation isn't allowed, not that it has a different effect.

Comment: I have tried replacing `real` to `double precision` in the declaration of `a`and `b` while using `source=0.0`. Then, gfortran and ifort indeed complained that the kind should be the same between the variables and source expression, while interestingly, Sun fortran allowed the use of mixed kinds (which might be compiler extension). So, overall, it looks safer to keep them of the same kind.. Thanks :)